# How to inherit or extend Website sale JS in Odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

I need to add one extra line in MyCard hover popup screen, I need to do this in separate custom module, how can i extend the website_sale.js file , 
i need to modify the code in below $.get method,

```
$.get("/shop/cart", {'type': 'popover'})
                    .then(function (data) {
                        $(self).data("bs.popover").options.content =  data;
                        $(self).popover("show");
                        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                            $(self).trigger('mouseleave');
                        });
                    });
```

Please anyone provide me an idea to extend or inherit this code.

Comment: You can take reference from one of odoo-v10 module "website_sale_options" in that module it's from it's JS file you can take reference because in that they already inherited "Website_Sale" module.